# @WebService portName element is not allowed on SEI

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have the defined the Interface as below for web service. It is giving me and two errors in @Webservice annotation:

> 1. @WebService portName element is not allowed on SEI
> 2. @WebService serviceName element is not allowed on SEI

How can I fix this? Thanks in Advance.

#### My code:

```
@WebService(name = "TestMartCatalog", portName="TestMartCatalogPort", serviceName ="TestMartCatalogService",targetNamespace = "http://www.testmart.com")
public interface ProductCatalogInterface {


@WebMethod (action="fetch Categories", operationName="fetchCategories")
public abstract List<String> getProductCategories();
@WebMethod 
public abstract List<String> getProducts(String category);
@WebMethod 
public abstract boolean addProduct(String category, String product);
@WebMethod 
public abstract List<Product> getProductsv2(String category);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. We cannot use portName and serviceName as mentioned by the error in SEI. we have to use it in the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

The **@WebService** annotation is marking a class as a web service endpoint.

If you are adding it to the Interface, it does not support attributes like **portName**, **serviceName**, or **endpointInterface**, which are getting used in the implementation class.